# What does ADMManifest.checkManifestAuthoredProperly() actually do?

Tags: android, android-manifest, amazon-device-messaging

Amazon Device Messaging has a static method used to ensure that the AndroidManifest.xml file is setup properly to allow for ADM messages to be sent and received.  It is a void method.  What does this method actually do?  What happens when the manifest is not setup correctly?

Comment: Well, since it doesn't return anything, I'd say it's a good bet that it throws an exception if errors are detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Amazon developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=11859):

> The manifest check method queries Android's package manager to ensure you have the correct entries in your manifest (permissions, exported receiver). It also checks that you have an API key embedded, but does not check if it is valid. If any of these checks fail, it throws an IllegalStateException.
>
> Also worth nothing: the manifest checker is intended to be used during ADM integration to quickly find issues in your manifest, and should not be put into the critical path of your application